# Someone who walks on a tightrope

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word or concise phrase for someone who walks on a tightrope?

Comment: The word is "tightrope walker".

Comment: Yes: a [tightrope walker](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tightrope_walker) :)

Comment: This question can be answered from Google Dictionary by searching [ define tightrope walker ].

Comment: Does ```politician``` count?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The precise term is [***funambulist***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/funambulist?q=funambulist). In addition to *tightrope walker*, of course.

Comment: Don't actually use *funambulist*. It will sent people scurrying to their dictionaries. *Tightrope walker* is widely understood.

Answer (score 1):

I have also heard *tightrope artist.*

Answer (score 1):

Also an [equilibrist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/equilibrist), though the definitions don't indicate what other classes of equilibrists there are besides funambulists.